# Magento 2.2: How to save data from custom field in sales_order_address table?

Tags: magento2, custom-field

I added a custom field in checkout and want to save data in **sales_order_address** table. I successfully saved that data in quote, sales_order and sales_order_grid tables.

Here is my **UpgradeSchema.php** code:

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function upgrade(
    SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
) {
    $installer = $setup;

    $installer->startSetup();

    $eavTable1 = $installer->getTable('quote');
    $eavTable2 = $installer->getTable('sales_order');
    $eavTable3 = $installer->getTable('sales_order_grid');
    $eavTable4 = $installer->getTable('sales_order_address');

    $columns = [
       'custom_field' => [
           'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
           'nullable' => true,
           'comment' => 'Custom Field',
       ]

    ];

    $connection = $installer->getConnection();
    foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
      $connection->addColumn($eavTable1, $name, $definition);
      $connection->addColumn($eavTable2, $name, $definition);
      $connection->addColumn($eavTable3, $name, $definition);
      $connection->addColumn($eavTable4, $name, $definition);
    }

    $installer->endSetup();
  }
 }
```

And here is my **di.xml** file:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
  <plugin name="save_to_quote_table" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Quote\SaveToQuote" sortOrder="10"/>
  </type>
 <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="custom_field" xsi:type="string">sales_order.custom_field</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Address" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Address">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="custom_field" xsi:type="string">sales_order.custom_field</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
</config>
```

The **custom_field** column shows up in all 4 tables (quote, sales_order, sales_order_grid and sales_order_address), but only saves data in 3 of them (quote, sales_order and sales_order_grid). How do I save it in **sales_order_address** too ? What am I missing ?

And if I successfully save it in sales_order_address, can I use that field in **Customer Configuration / Address Templates / HTML** like this: **{{depend custom_field}}Custom field:{{var custom_field}}{{/depend}}** ?